# i18next failing to load translation file: "there is a typo"

Tags: json, i18next

I've created translation file, validated it at [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/), ensured the translation file was located at /locales/translation-en.json.

I consistently get the error,

```
There is a typo in: locales/translation-en.json
```

I'm stumped ... here's the translation json I have.

```
{
   "tab":{
      "legionella":"LEGIONELLA",
      "logbook":"LOGBOOK"
   },
   "representative":{
      "tag":"Representative: __rep__ &#8212; Phone: __phone__ &#8212; ",
      "email":"Click here to email your rep"
   },
   "portlet":{
      "contacts":{
         "title":"Contacts",
         "type":"Contact<br>Type",
         "name":"Contact<br>Name",
         "phone":"Phone<br>Number",
         "type_context_1":"Owner",
         "type_context_2":"Maintenance",
         "type_context_3":"Other"
      },
      "samples":{
         "title":"Legionella Samples",
         "sampleDate":"Sample<br>Date",
         "transmitForm":"Transmittal<br>Form",
         "certOfAnalysis":"Certificate<br>of Analysis",
         "concentration":"Concentration<br>(UFC/L)",
         "correctAction":"Corrective<br>Action",
         "range_context_1":"Interference",
         "range_context_2":"Less than 10,000 UFC/L",
         "range_context_3":"Between 10,000 to 1,000,000 UFC/L",
         "range_context_4":"Greater than 1,000,000 UFC/L"
      },
      "serviceReports":{
         "title":"Service Reports",
         "date":"Report<br>Date"
      },
      "maintenance":{
         "title":"Maintenance Programs",
         "popup":"Create New Maintenance Program",
         "type":"Program<br>Type",
         "date":"Effective<br>Date",
         "document":"Program<br>Document",
         "type_context_1":"Water Treatment",
         "type_context_2":"Mechanical",
         "type_context_3":"Schematic",
         "type_context_4":"O&M Manual",
         "popup_type":"Type",
         "popup_date":"Effective Date",
         "popup_document":"Document",
         "popup_save":"Save Maintenance Program"
      },
      "history":{
         "title":"System History",
         "popup":"Create New System History Entry",
         "date":"Event<br>Date",
         "type":"Event<br>Type",
         "details":"Event<br>Details",
         "type_context_1":"Breakage",
         "type_context_2":"Repair",
         "type_context_3":"Decontamination",
         "type_context_4":"Replacement"
      },
      "reminders":{
         "title":"Reminders",
         "date":"Date",
         "description":"Description"
      },
      "emails":{
         "title":"Emails",
         "date":"Date",
         "subject":"Subject",
         "recipient":"Recipient"
      }
   },
   "common":{
      "view":"View",
      "registryList":"Registry: ",
      "signout":"Sign Out"
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you need to escape "/"-characters so in this case : "UFC/L" must become "UFC\/L". Again : i couldn't test this yet

Comment: Sadly no, that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the issue.  I didn't give ALL the details required in the original question.  What I failed to let everyone know was that the json file resided in Netsuite.  Netsuite doesn't like serving up .json files.  When I converted it to .json.txt, all was well in the world. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just in the event someone missed the obvious..

**JSON, unlike Javascipt, requires the keys be quoted.**

Valid JSON:

```
 { "foo": "bar" }
```

Invalid JSON:

```
 { foo: "bar" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this question pops high in Google when search for "i18next there is a typo in", here's what you can do.

Use a JSON validation tool. If it's not valid, correct your mistakes and try again.